# .aspx page JS will fire Onload scripts before controls seem to be rendered for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have code which will fire on load, and fetch the object based on the ID.  It returns null.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      var TV = $find("FieldTreeViewer");
   });
</script>
<body>
   <telerik:RadTreeView OnClientNodeExpanded="nodePopulating" OnClientNodeClicked="checkLeaf" runat="server" ID = "FieldTreeViewer">
   </telerik:RadTreeView>
</body>
```

It seems that onload will return null, but if i go into the console and reenter the var TV statement, it will assign it.  I figure that the Control was NOT rendered yet.  How would I go about making it so that the page renders BEFORE firing the function?

I am aware of asp having onLoad, onInit, etc, but this is purely markup, there is no magic behind the scenes.

**I just thought that markup would render, and then when the page finishes loading, i could call a function to reference the control by ID.**

Comment: Is the control being created on page load and not ready?

Comment: Interesting... have you tried moving that function to `$(window).load(function () {
  var TV = $find("FieldTreeViewer");
});` instead?

Comment: I am not sure how to tell.  That control is cpy+pasted right from my code.  I dont have anything in onLoad, etc in the backend.

Comment: @Icarus seems to have the function which works.  interesting.  I guess it is when the entire window is loaded, and not when the doc is ready is best for firing off code related to controls.

Comment: @Fallenreaper there's no magic there. That means `$find` is relying in some that isn't available when the DOM is ready. I will post my code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing your code on window.load instead, as so:

```
$(window).load(function () 
{ 
    var TV = $find("FieldTreeViewer"); 
});
```